# want to construct data frame faster in python

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create the data frame by connecting to a cluster having GPU. The code what i have written is basically creates a data frame of the CIFAR image data set. the code is given below :

```
import Image
import numpy as np
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd
os.chdir('./train')
for file in list(glob.glob('*.png')):
    img = Image.open(file)
    img.load()
    data = np.asarray( img, dtype="int32")
    a = np.array(data)
    b = a.ravel()
    c = a.flatten()
    #print(c)
    df = pd.DataFrame([c])
    df = df.append(df, ignore_index = True)
```

how to get the result faster as it takes huge time due to the large number of images in the training data set. Thanks in advance

Comment: maybe rezina  https://github.com/fujiaoliu/rezina would be help.

Comment: try multithreading or multiprocessing